# Why does this qtip2 show blank content on 2nd click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, qtip2

I have a [qtip2](http://www.qtip2.com) tooltip which is loading static HTML content from the next element. The tooltip successfully loads the content on the first hover. On the second hover the tooltip's content panel is blank.

http://jsfiddle.net/adamtsiopani/m4hohp4e/

**HTML**

```html
<a href="#" class="tooltip" title="My Title">hover here</a>
<div class="tooltip-content">
    <!-- some content -->
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.tooltip-content {
    display: none;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```js
$('a.tooltip').qtip({
    content: {
        title: {
            text: function(event, api) {
                return $(api.target).attr('title');
            }
        },
        text: function(event, api) {
            return $(api.target).next('.tooltip-content');
        }
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/adamtsiopani/m4hohp4e/

**UPDATE**

I understand now why this is happening - on the first hover, the `.tooltip-content` element gets moved into the tooltip which is then placed at end of the DOM. So it's no longer the 'next' element... but I don't understand how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than passing the actual `.tooltip-content` DOM node/jQuery element to qtip for the popup's text:

```
text: function(event, api) {
    return $(api.target).next('.tooltip-content');
}
```

You can pass it html instead:

```
text: function(event, api) {
    return $(api.target).next('.tooltip-content').html();
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m4hohp4e/15/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$('a.tooltip').qtip({
    content: {
        title: {
            text: function(event, api) {
                return $(api.target).attr('title');
            }
        },
        text: function(event, api) {
            return $(api.target).parent().find('.tooltip-content')
        }
    }
});
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/m4hohp4e/11/)

```
$(api.target).next('.tooltip-content');
//qtip changes DOM after you first hover on the element,
//so you have to use different selector
```

Comment: @Alex thanks for that, but it doesn't work in my example. It's true that it works on the JSFiddle, but I think that's just because the DOM is uncomplicated. If you use on a full HTML page, the element is no longer in the `parent()` container either - it gets moved into the tooltip which is place before `</body>` in the DOM